# LINQ to SQL, condition on foreign entities

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

In SQL, it'd be done as such:

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE SchoolId IN
    (SELECT id FROM School WHERE Name LIKE '%elementary%')
```

How do I implement this with LINQ? I've tried the following:

```
var list = context.Students.Where(x => context.Schools.Where(r => r.Name.Contains("elementary").Select(r => r.Id).Contains(x.SchoolId))
```

but it's not giving me what I want, unfortunately...

I know it's possible to retrieve all the `Id`s from the `School` table first, but I think it'd take a heavy toll on the performance. Preferably I'd like LINQ to SQL to handle everything; I can't do this using vanilla SQL because I need stuff to be dynamic and currently LINQ is the best solution for me.

The code above is all for illustration purposes; what I'm doing is a tad different (but more or less the same). I really do need some help on this; if you need any more information just feel free to ask.

**EDIT:** My bad, I missed out a field. It works, but the results didn't show up because I was missing that field... So sorry...

Comment: "it's not giving me what I want" - what do you mean?  The right results or the right SQL?

Comment: Um, when I go debug and view the query it generates in the `IQueryable`, it's a no-go... Completely different from the SQL I wrote up there. Results-wise, I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The first use of Contains is on a string object to see if the string contains the substring "elementary". The second use of Contains is on a list and checks to see if the first result list contains SchoolId.

```
var sublist = from s in context.Schools
              where s.Name.Contains("elementary")
              select id;

var list = from s in context.Students
           where sublist.Contains(s.SchoolId)
           select s;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var result = from st in context.Student
             from sc in context.Schools
             where sc.Name.Contains("elementary") && sc.SchoolId == st.SchoolId
             select st;
```

I am a bit hazy on the syntax, pardon me. But this should point you to the right direction.